# sparse outer product in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to compute an adjacency matrix of sorts in R to account for network autocorrelation in a dyadic model.  I can construct the matrix I need using outer(), but this will not scale unless I can figure out how to have R give me results in some sort of sparse matrix format:

```
N = 10
g = simplify(watts.strogatz.game(1, N, 2, 0.05))
EL = get.edgelist(g)
ego_out = outer(EL[,1], EL[,1], '==')
alter_out = outer(EL[,2], EL[,2], '==')
ea_out = outer(EL[,1], EL[,2], '==')
ae_out = outer(EL[,2], EL[,1], '==')

pair_out = ego_out | alter_out  
opp_out = ea_out | ae_out 

pair_out | opp_out
```

This obviously does not scale (if you are brave try setting N = 10000000).

Comment: Did you look into `Matrix` and/or `SparseM` packages - they do support sparse matrix operation.

Comment: @user102890 Yes, I did not see anything like outer( ..., '==')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have below works, tho it is quite slow.

```
outer_Matrix = function(X, Y, FUN = '==', ...){
  require('Matrix')
  dX <- length(X)
  no.nx <- is.null(names(X))
  if (!no.nx) 
    nx <- list(names(X))
  dY <- length(Y)
  no.ny <- is.null(names(Y))
  if (!no.ny) 
    ny <- list(names(Y))

    # instead iterate over each item in X, check against Y
    robj <- Matrix(FALSE, nrow = dX, ncol = dY)
    rows = which(X %in% Y)

    FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
    for(i in rows){
      robj[i,] <- FUN(X[i], Y, ...)
      if(i %% 1000==0)
      print(i)
    }

  if (!(no.nx && no.ny)) {
    if (no.nx) 
      nx <- vector("list", length(dX))
    else if (no.ny) 
      ny <- vector("list", length(dY))
    dimnames(robj) <- c(nx, ny)
  }
  robj

}
```